# Do the common terminal operations not work with Stream<java.lang.Byte>?

Tags: java, byte, java-8, java-stream

I have a simple `Stream` that is meant to work on Bytes:

```
List<Byte> byteList = Arrays.stream(new Byte[]{0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4})
        .map(b -> b >> 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The compiler gives:

> Error: incompatible types: inference variable `T` has incompatible bounds
>
> equality constraints: `java.lang.Byte`
>
> lower bounds: `java.lang.Integer`

And this also does not work:

```
Optional<Byte> aByte = Arrays.stream(new Byte[]{0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4})
        .map(b -> b >> 1)
        .findFirst();
```

> Error: incompatible types: `java.util.Optional<java.lang.Integer>` cannot be converted to `java.util.Optional<java.lang.Byte>`

I did not find any documentation stating that streams do not support `Byte`. Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b >> 1` returns an int which can't be automatically cast to byte. You can just add a cast:

```
.map(b -> (byte) (b >> 1))
```

Comment: Thanks. For some reason Intellij IDEA kept telling me that the map was an operation from Byte to Byte...

Comment: And it is, but your implementation returned an int

Comment: Though, if you are at this point, you may also use `IntStream.of(0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4) .mapToObj(b -⁠> (byte)(b>>1)).collect(Collectors.toList());` as there is no real reason to have `Byte` objects as source…